# Как выровнять див вертикально по центру внутри другого дива?

Tags: css

В таблицах есть свойство вертикального выравнивания 
valign. Как можно в дивах выравнивать содержимое
по центру вертикально. При условии, что див внешний,
и див внутреннис с содержимым не имеют постоянной высоты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут пример с объяснениями](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Answer (score 3):

В CSS:

```
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/zypz2/

Если нужна поддержка IE ниже восьмой версии, то у внутреннего элемента добавьте:

```
margin-top: expression(this.offsetHeight < this.parentNode.offsetHeight ? parseInt((this.parentNode.offsetHeight - this.offsetHeight) / 2) + "px" : "0");
```

Comment: Этот способ не поддерживается IE.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов: Поддерживается начиная с IE 8. Для IE7 лечится с `expression`, ответ обновил.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
.align_center
{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.align_center:after
{
content: '';
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.align_center_to_left
{
position: relative;
right: 50%;
float: right;
}
.align_center_to_right
{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
right: -50%;
}
</style>
<div class="align_center" style="border: 1px dashed red; color: red;">
Выравниваем относительно этого блока.
    <div class="align_center_to_left">
        <div class="align_center_to_right" style="margin: 1em 0; border: 1px dashed green; color: green;">
            Ширина блока зависит от&nbsp;размера надписи.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    #outer {
        width: 50%;
        background: yellow;
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
    }
    #inner {
        width: 50%;
        background: blue;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

Как то так?